# Mixed Raw Egg Left in Fridge

Tags: kashrut-kosher, eggs, danger, ruach-rah

Seeing that leaving raw [eggs overnight](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/shelled-eggs-peeled-onions-and-garlic-left-overnight-keeping-products-ruach-raah-free/) is a problem according as "the overwhelming majority of Poskim hold that the Gemara continues to be relevant nowadays" ([Nidda 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.17a.11?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) - ה' דברים הן שהעושה אותן מתחייב בנפשו ודמו בראשו
האוכל שום קלוף ובצל קלוף וביצה קלופה), does accidentally mixing the raw egg into a mixture for a chicken batter retain its ruach-rah if it's potentially batel bshishim?

Comment: Why would you think it’s a problem? It’s best to summarize the link contents in the post itself.

Comment: @donielf also why mixing it would make a difference. (also why ruach ra should scare anyone... what exactly is it going to do to you?)

Comment: Why might Batel beShishim be relevant? We aren't talking about a Halakhic prohibition. The question is just if that little volume of ruach ra food is still dangerous. Seeing as there is no detectable danger in day old onions etc. ever, there's no way to practically answer this question.

Comment: @DoubleAA **possibly** the rules of *ruach ra'ah* in foods may have the same halachot as *sakanah*. E.g., I believe that if a small amount of fish is mixed with meat, it is *batel beshishim*.

Comment: I'd be curious if the *ruach ra'ah* stipulation regarding raw eggs came about b/c the time of the Gemarah there was no refrigeration. A raw refrigerated egg may not even have these conditions.

Comment: @DanF You can eat arsenic if there's sixty times as much volume of cholent??

Comment: We have a M.Y. question, I believe, re the fish and meat problem, and I believe it does state that it's batel beshishim despite the *sakanah* concern.

Answer (score 1):

One of the poskim in Baltimore told me that his mesorah is to follow Rav Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg z"tl who wasn't *machmir* for the *gemara b'dieved*. (The Rav also mentioned it's still considered fine *l'chatchila* by putting a grain or two of salt into the egg for it to be considered mixed to remove the sakana issue.)